# Invoice Monetary Format

Tags: joomla, contributions, invoice, display, currency

I'm not really good in any sorts of programing, haven't used smarty before. I want to **change the monetary format in our Invoice**.

```
{$amount|crmMoney:$currency}
```

This code displays $1000.00, but I need $1,000.00 or $1,000 , how can I achieve this?

my civicrm version is 5.1.1, joomla 3.9.4, CRM runs in Window 7

updates: 
1. thanks to Joachim I notice decimal is working fine, thousand separators is not, whatever I input in Localization Currency> Thousand Separator, nothing displays.

2. upgraded Civicrm to 5.11.0, problem persist.

3. the problem is not in {$amount|crmMoney:$currency} or MONEY.php, I think something's wrong with my settings.

Comment: Is your server on windows?

Comment: Yes, it's win 7

Comment: Ok I will post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crmMoney function uses php's money_format() function to format the numbers. On Windows, this function does not exist! (https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-650)

However you can use crmNumberFormat to format it yourself, and add in the currency symbol manually, for example, assuming you want the US dollar symbol:

Instead of `{$amount|crmMoney:$currency}`, use

`${$amount|crmNumberFormat:2}`

Note the extra $ at the beginning, which outputs the literal dollar sign. The above will also use the separator and decimal point characters you have set up on the admin screen.

Comment: This works for the invoice, thank you so much for the explanation and answer! Additional question, what is the best environment to run CIVICRM, if it's not windows?

Comment: Windows is normally fine, but all the developers seem to have macs for some reason, but that's a whole other topic. The main test environment that the offical tests run on is debian and ubuntu linux.

Comment: another solution http://blog.nirvan.pagooah.com/fixing-undefined-function-money_format-in-windows/ but I havn't tried, I will comment again if this works

Answer (score 2):

If you need to change the settings globally, not just for the single statement, you have the option under Administer -> Localization -> Languages, Currency, Locations. There you can define the "Thousands Separator" as well as the "Decimal Delimiter".

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Joachim, it's like this by default, the thousand separator doesn't work also in Individual> Contribution.

Comment: The settings look all just like mine. I just checked this in my Civi test installation (version 7.11.0 with Wordpress 5.1) by trying to use the "=" character as a thousands separator - and it worked for screen displays of currency amounts as well as in the printed invoice. Therefore, I assume something else is interfering here. Perhaps there are some customizations in your code/template or some extension may influence this?

Comment: Maybe it's because i used CIVI 5.1.1 Joomla 3.9.4 , i don't modify codes too much as I'm not sure how they work, never install any templates too, and thank you for helping btw :)

Comment: Oh, I made typo - it's of course version 5.11.0.

Comment: Is there any update on this? Is there a way to get the thousands delimiter to work?